# Possible to supply IKEA Tradfri with Malware? (How to detect / remove)

Tags: malware, worm

Maybe I'm overly cautious here, but I bought a 2nd hand IKEA Tradfri lightbulb. The package was opened so whoever owned it before had access to the bulb itself.

My question is: Am I too cautious assuming there MIGHT be some form of malware on it?

Background: A ZigBee worm was assumed to be possible a decade back (https://eyalro.net/project/iotworm.html) and apparently used shortly after (https://www.theverge.com/2016/11/3/13507126/iot-drone-hack). So a valid approach for a hacker could be to buy some lightbulbs, equip them with malware, return them to the store using IKEA's return policy and wait for someone to install these at home.

Second question: I assume a factory reset of the bulb should do the trick (unless a potential malware is very sophisticated and implements countermeasures for this). So my plan would be to

1. Disconnect all ZigBee devices in the house
2. Connect an old Dirigea hub
3. Hook up the suspect lightbulb to a power source, connect it, factory reset it, then reset it
4. Connect the reset bulb to the "normal" network I use

Any flaws in that plan?

Comment: "Is it possible?" - of course it is *possible* but the question is if it is *likely* and I don't think it is

Comment: If the firmware was overwritten, then a factory reset won't work.